# problems while executing a sql command in vb

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem with a sql query. Through the query I am trying to search database for any occurrences of string (can be anything) in a column using the SQL LIKE command. The problem is that it works fine for most of the strings say john, jim, ji"m , but does not work when i include the following characters which are ( ' , { , } , and a single quotation mark). MYSQL query takes care of these special cases by putting them in [] block whenever user enters them .

But i am getting the following error when i go to query the database using the GetSelectCommand() in VB.NET

> Exception Details: 
>   System.ApplicationException:
>  Number of
>   values provided must be equal to the
>   number of placeholders in query.

I have checked the query over and over again .. but its fine .

My database server is Sql Server 2008.

So my application throws the exception in this command:

```
Using reader As MustDisposeDataReader = _
    pmSystem.DatabaseManager.GetSelectCommand(selectStatementBuilder.ToString(), New Object() {})
```

Where `MustDisposeDataReader` is an instance of a class in an internally developed library, which  inherits from `System.Object`. `pmSystem` is an instance of the class `PlanManagerSystem` which implements the commandlayer. `GetSelectCommand()` takes the select command

Comment: Please post your VB calling code.  The likelihood is that the problem is there somewhere.

Comment: VB, SQL and LIKE are a very tricky affair to be sure. The syntax obviously has to be perfect. I point this out because we get used to much being done behind the scenes for us, not so with that combination. As stated, you have to show code to get anywhere.

Comment: its a microsoft sql server management studio 2008

Comment: So my application throws the exception in this command...
Using reader As MustDisposeDataReader=pmSystem.DatabaseManager.GetSelectCommand(selectStatementBuilder.ToString, New Object() {})

where MustDisposeDataReader is an object of  class in internally developed library .. the class MustDisposeDataReader inherits System.object

pmsystem is object of class PlanManagerSystem which implements the commandlayer

GetSelectCommand() takes the select command

Comment: We need to also see the SQL being used =)

Answer (score 0):

Your single quotes are probably formatted incorrectly.  Since it says the number of values are wrong it looks like your single quotes are off.